# Log in Loop in Ubuntu 18.04, after I changed something in my $PATH, but startx works

Tags: 18.04, login-screen

As per the title, I stuck in a log in loop, I tried everything from Xauthority, installing lightdm and purging the Nvidia, but none of them works.

I messed up after I tried to install Flutter environment, and I think I changed something in my $PATH. But I'm struggling a lot with it.

So, as I found in some suggestions, I looked up in the .xsession-errors and this appear:

```
Xsession: X session started for manik at Sun Mar 29 17:29:20 WITA 2020
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/manik/.Xauthority
localuser:manik being added to access control list
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting MAIL=/var/mail/manik
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USER=manik
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_CSD=0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHLVL=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOME=/home/manik
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting OLDPWD=/home/manik
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LESS=-R
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT4_IM_MODULE=xim
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HUSHLOGIN=FALSE
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LSCOLORS=Gxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PAGER=less
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOMEBREW_NO_ANALYTICS=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting NVM_DIR=/home/manik/.nvm
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LOGNAME=manik
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting JOURNAL_STREAM=9:38216
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting _=/usr/bin/startx
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting TERM=linux
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting RBENV_SHELL=zsh
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting WINDOWPATH=3
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PATH=./bin:./node_modules/.bin:/home/manik/.pyenv/bin:/home/manik/.rbenv/shims:/home/manik/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/sbin
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting INVOCATION_ID=0a558d87417b47839b07897fd39a2620
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANG=en_US.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting BUNDLER_EDITOR=subl  >/dev/null 2>&1 -a
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LD_PRELOAD=libgtk3-nocsd.so.0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XAUTHORITY=/home/manik/.Xauthority
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHELL=/usr/bin/zsh
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PYENV_VIRTUALENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PWD=/home/manik
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Show us guide you've followed to install Flutter

Comment: I followed a youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dzlfZmShpeQ
The thing is that I probably messed up in the .bashrc file. But when I tried to open it again, it was empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the video tutorial you've provided the author adds the next to the end of `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/you_user/flutter/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/home/you_user/tools/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/home/you_user/emulator"
export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME:/home/you_user"
```

To fix it

- make sure you have all `"` double quotes
- make sure you have correct paths specified by entering that folders: `cd /home/your_user/flutter/bin` and so on.
- or just comment out that lines with `#` symbol and check if it works

`export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME` could be enough I think.

Comment: Right! It didn't work the first time, so I tried to uninstall all Flutter dependencies and did what you recomended in here, it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: @ManiKAANgurah Ok. Glad to hear). Don't forget to make this answer accepted if it was useful.